# Finding an approximation to the Heaviside function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, analysis

I'm having difficulty answering this question:

**Questions statement:**

Consider the function:
              $
  f(x) = \begin{cases}
    0 & \text{if $x\leq 0$,}\\
    e^{-\frac{1}{x}} & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$

Show that there exists a positive function $g(x)\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ that cancels outside the interval $ ]-1,1[ $ and that satisfies:

$ 1=\int_{\mathbb{R}}^{} g(x) dx $.

**Thoughts on what to do**

1) I can show that $f$ is infinitely differentiable and define the function $g$ by  displacing $f$ over the interval $]-1,1[$ and define $g$ such that it's zero outside the interval $]-1,1[$ - this effectively solves the first part of the question

2) My problem is that I don't know how to guaranty the condition $ 1=\int_{\mathbb{R}}^{} g(x) dx $ without evaluating directly $ \int_{\mathbb{R}}^{} g(x) dx $ which in my mind doesn't have an analytical solution. I think it's the equality here that's got me stumped.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we define $f$ by
$$ f(x)=\left\{\begin{aligned}
&0 &\text{if } x\notin ]-1,1[ \\
&e^{-\frac{1}{1-x^2}} &\text{if } x\in ]-1,1[
\end{aligned}\right. $$
(this is kinda your function $f$) then $f$ is $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ and you can take
$$g=\frac{f}{\int_{\mathbb{R}}f}$$
I think this is the best example and the one expected.

Comment: wait I understand.... that works thanks so much

Comment: Use the linearity of the inegral : $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\lambda f=\lambda\int_{\mathbb{R}}f$, applying this with $\lambda=\frac{1}{\int_{\mathbb{R}}f}$ you get $\int_{\mathbb{R}}{g}=\frac{\int_{\mathbb{R}}f}{\int_{\mathbb{R}}f}=1$.

Comment: yeah - it took me a few to catch on... thanks guys